# How to group a data.frame by date?

Tags: r, aggregate

I have a .csv file in the following format:

```
Date       ,     Time  , Value
1899-01-01 ,  4:00:00  ,    1
1899-01-01 ,  4:01:00  ,    2
1899-01-01 ,  4:02:00  ,    3
1899-01-01 ,  4:03:00  ,    4
1899-01-01 ,  4:04:00  ,    5
1900-08-22 , 22:00:00  ,  101
1900-08-22 , 22:01:00  ,  102
2013-08-29 ,  4:00:00  , 1000
2013-02-29 ,  4:02:00  , 1001
2013-02-29 ,  4:03:00  , 1002
```

Is it possible to `group by date` to produce a `data.table` in the the following format:

```
Date      , Vector(variable length)
1899-02-28, c(1,2,3,4,5)
1900-08-22, c(101,102)
1900-08-22, c(1000,1001,1002)
```

This is the best that I have so far (after a day of attempts):

```
raw <- read.csv(pathName, header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
groupedByDate <- split(raw, raw$Date)
```

However, this seems to produce a very wide table with one column for each date, which is not very close to what I want.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What about using `aggregate` on a `data.frame` named "mydf" as follows:

```
> temp <- aggregate(Value ~ Date, mydf, as.vector) 
> temp
         Date         Value
1 1899-01-01  1, 2, 3, 4, 5
2 1900-08-22       101, 102
3 2013-02-29     1001, 1002
4 2013-08-29           1000
```

The "Value" column is now a `list` which contains your vectors.

```
> temp$Value
$`0`
[1] 1 2 3 4 5

$`1`
[1] 101 102

$`2`
[1] 1001 1002

$`3`
[1] 1000
```

What you were probably looking for with `split` is:

```
> split(mydf$Value, mydf$Date)
$`1899-01-01 `
[1] 1 2 3 4 5

$`1900-08-22 `
[1] 101 102

$`2013-02-29 `
[1] 1001 1002

$`2013-08-29 `
[1] 1000
```

Comment: Thanks, this works absolutely brilliantly! I'll mark yours as the answer, as you were first.

Answer (score 3):

Use `aggregate` and `paste0`

```
> aggregate(Value ~ Date, data=DF, FUN=paste0 )
         Date         Value
1 1899-01-01  1, 2, 3, 4, 5
2 1900-08-22       101, 102
3 2013-02-29     1001, 1002
4 2013-08-29           1000
```

Comment: Thank you ever so much for this answer, very much appreciated. p.s. I actually wanted a vector of numbers, so its "c" instead of "paste".