# Transposition with aggregation of data.table

Tags: r, aggregate, data.table, transpose

Suppose that we have `data.table` like that:

```
    TYPE KEY  VALUE
1:  1    A    10
2:  1    B    10
3:  1    A    40
4:  2    B    20
5:  2    B    40
```

I need to generate the following aggregated `data.table` (numbers are sums of values for given TYPE and KEY):

```
    TYPE A    B
1:  1    50   10
2:  2    0    60
```

In a real life problem there are a lot of different values for KEY so it's impossible to hardcode them.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15142660/how-to-group-a-data-frame-by-date.

Answer (score 1):

One way I could think of is:

```
# to ensure all levels are present when using `tapply`
DT[, KEY := factor(KEY, levels=unique(KEY))]
DT[, as.list(tapply(VALUE, KEY, sum)), by = TYPE]
#    TYPE  A  B
# 1:    1 50 10
# 2:    2 NA 60
```