# Group and Sum By Factor

Tags: r, ggplot2, sum, aggregate

I have data like this:

```
> head(df)
                  Date IsWin
20 2014-07-13 00:00:00  True
21 2014-08-01 00:00:00  True
22 2014-08-05 00:00:00 False
23 2014-06-28 00:00:00  True
24 2014-05-31 00:00:00  True
25 2014-06-06 00:00:00  True
```

I would like to group by Date and sum by IsWin (which should be a factor of 1 or -1).

I have read through this but it doesn't really deal with factors, so I don't know how to apply it [How to group a data.frame by date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15142660/how-to-group-a-data-frame-by-date)

Ultimately, I would like to pass the grouped and summed data to a bar chart to show the number of wins or losses, something like [ggplot2 and a Stacked Bar Chart with Negative Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13734368/ggplot2-and-a-stacked-bar-chart-with-negative-values)

The following outputs a table which is quite helpful to seeing what I want; however, I would like to translate this into a bar chart for better visuals:

```
> table(df[,1],df[,2])

                      False True
  2014-05-25 00:00:00     1    0
  2014-05-29 00:00:00     1    0
  2014-05-30 00:00:00     2    0
  2014-05-31 00:00:00     0    1
  2014-06-06 00:00:00     0    1
  2014-06-13 00:00:00     1    0
  2014-06-14 00:00:00     0    1
  2014-06-18 00:00:00     1    0
  2014-06-19 00:00:00     0    1
  2014-06-23 00:00:00     1    0
  2014-06-24 00:00:00     1    0
  2014-06-25 00:00:00     1    0
  2014-06-27 00:00:00     0    1
  2014-06-28 00:00:00     1    2
  2014-07-02 00:00:00     1    0
  2014-07-11 00:00:00     1    0
  2014-07-13 00:00:00     0    2
  2014-07-31 00:00:00     0    1
  2014-08-01 00:00:00     0    1
  2014-08-05 00:00:00     1    0
  2014-08-07 00:00:00     1    0
  2014-08-12 00:00:00     0    1
```

Here is my actual structure:

```
df <- structure(list(Date = c("2014-07-13 00:00:00", "2014-08-01 00:00:00", 
"2014-08-05 00:00:00", "2014-06-28 00:00:00", "2014-05-31 00:00:00", 
"2014-06-06 00:00:00", "2014-06-14 00:00:00", "2014-05-25 00:00:00", 
"2014-06-24 00:00:00", "2014-06-28 00:00:00", "2014-05-30 00:00:00", 
"2014-06-18 00:00:00", "2014-07-02 00:00:00", "2014-07-11 00:00:00", 
"2014-05-29 00:00:00", "2014-06-19 00:00:00", "2014-07-31 00:00:00", 
"2014-06-27 00:00:00", "2014-06-23 00:00:00", "2014-05-30 00:00:00", 
"2014-07-13 00:00:00", "2014-08-12 00:00:00", "2014-06-13 00:00:00", 
"2014-06-25 00:00:00", "2014-06-28 00:00:00", "2014-08-07 00:00:00"
), IsWin = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L
), .Label = c("False", "True"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Date", 
"IsWin"), row.names = 20:45, class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
ddf2 = data.frame(with(df, table(Date, IsWin)))

ggplot(ddf2)+
    geom_bar(aes(x=Date, y=Freq, fill=IsWin), stat='identity', position='dodge')+
    theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=45, size=10, hjust=1, vjust=1))
```

[image]

EDIT: 
For negative bars:

```
ddf2$new = ifelse(ddf2$IsWin=='True', 1,-1)

ggplot(ddf2)+
    geom_bar(data=ddf2[ddf2$new>0,], aes(x=Date, y=Freq*new, fill=IsWin), stat='identity')+
    geom_bar(data=ddf2[ddf2$new<0,], aes(x=Date, y=Freq*new, fill=IsWin), stat='identity')+
    theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=45, size=10, hjust=1, vjust=1))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but the output is different from what I was expecting.  For instance, look at 2014-06-28.  I would like for the red to go to negative one, and the blue to go to 2 since the score for that day was 2 wins and one loss.  Basically, I would like the losses to be multiplied by negative one, so that they display more obviously as losses (sub zero values). Also, I added `df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date)` so that the dates display as dates. Can you tell me how to multiply the losses by negative 1?

Comment: Note:  I have tried `df$IsWin <- factor(df$IsWin, levels=c(-1,1))` but it creates an empty chart.

Comment: Please see my EDIT in the answer above.

Answer (score 1):

How about this? You use `group_by()` in the [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr) package. You can group your data in the following way. You can summarise (count) how many TRUE and FALSE exist for each date. Using this data frame, you can create a stacked bar chart.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

### Create a sample data set
dates <- rep(c("2014-08-01", "2014-08-02"), each = 10, times = 1)
win <- rep(c("TRUE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "TRUE", "TRUE"), each = 1, times = 4)

foo <- data.frame(cbind(dates, win))
foo$dates <- as.character(foo$dates)

ana <- foo %>%
         group_by(dates, win) %>%
         summarize(count = n())

# ana
# Source: local data frame [4 x 3]
# Groups: date

#        dates   win count
# 1 2014-08-01 FALSE     4
# 2 2014-08-01  TRUE     6
# 3 2014-08-02 FALSE     4
# 4 2014-08-02  TRUE     6

bob <- ggplot(ana, aes(x=dates, y=count, fill=win)) +
         geom_bar(stat="identity") +
         scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,10,by = 1))
```

**UPDATED OPTION**

After seeing comments, I came up with this idea. It has two new things. One is to convert positive values to negative ones when the win condition is FALSE. The other is a new ggplot. I am sure there are better ways of doing things. But, I would like to contribute this idea here.

```
ana <- foo %>%
    group_by(dates, win) %>%
    summarize(count = n())

# If there is FALSE in ith row in the win column, make the value of ith row in the
# count column negative. If you can avoid a loop and achieve the same goal, that
# may be the best option. But, I do not have any ideas in my mind yet.

for(i in 1:nrow(ana)){

    if(ana$win[[i]] == "FALSE"){

    ana$count[[i]] <- -abs(ana$count[[i]])

    }
}

bob <- ggplot(data=ana, aes(x=dates, y=count, fill=win)) +
       geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge())
```

Does this fulfil your requirements?

Comment: Thanks; but it seems like the dates overlap on the x axis.

Comment: I set up dates as date. But that screwed up the x axis. I change dates to character here. On my machine, I do not have the issue any more. Hope this will do for you.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  Do you know how to multiply the false wins by negative one?  I would like for the losses to show as negative values and the wins to show as positive values to make my visualization more comprehensive.

Comment: I just updated my suggestion. Does this work for you?

Comment: Thanks for updating and commenting the code.  The other answer uses a little simpler syntax `ddf2$new = ifelse(ddf2$IsWin=='True', 1,-1)` so will go with that one; but thanks so much :)

Comment: All good. If you just need to draw a figure, there is no need to use dplyr here. The other approach will do.